# Twilio Send SMS throw exeption Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, twilio, apex, twilio-api

I am trying to send and SMS using Twilio but getting an error. Earlier it was working fine but now I am getting an exception : TwilioRestException: Script-thrown exception.

I suspect its a enhancement in Salesforce but don't know how to fix it. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio recently deprecated the SMS/Messages resource and replaced with Messages resource. You can view the change log here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sms

I also encountered a similar issue and resolved by implementing the new process. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is a Twilio<>Salesforce Library you can use that doesn't have the issue:

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-salesforce

Comment: Hi Francis - can you explain what the issue is that the referenced library addresses? While the OP shared zero code in his question, understanding why your solution fixes the problem would be very useful for those coming in later.

Comment: The library hasn't been updated for 2 years and i still use it and hasn't had any issues in sending any messages. As they didn't show any code it's hard to figure out what the issue is but one way would be to try this library instead to see if the issue still occurs.  Then if it works it maybe an issue around how the REST call is created (eliminates any platform issues). I very much doubt it's anything platform related as all Apex code runs against a specific version of a release.